# Pulseaudio cpu usage above normal with no audio/video play

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, cpu

I've noticed on my default installation of Ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.11 on the Dell XPS 9510, that Pulseaudio uses a small amount of CPU all the time, around 6-7% (checked with the top command at CLI), and I haven't use the audio at all.

The system uptime is 3 days, and the CPU Time (total cpu usage from System Monitor) of Pulseaudio is 50 hours, then you have Firefox, Xorg and Gnome-shell, all of the with 20 hours of total CPU time.

It seems too much to me, especially when I haven't used anything that plays audio, no video, no YouTube since the last reboot, 3 days ago.

Is there a way to fine tune Pulseaudio to use less CPU, maybe is the sampling time?

Comment: Same here with Ubuntu 22.04, puseaudio uses 5% CPU constantly (although I don't play any sound).

Comment: If I close Chromium, then pulseaudio stops the CPU usage.

Comment: @guettli Maybe [file a bugreport](https://crbug.com/wizard) for chromium. :-)  A Google account is needed, and [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) are some guidelines.

Comment: My Ubuntu 22.04 shows pulseaudio  with 0%CPU and 0,3% MEM in "top". Manjaro distro the same. Firefox&Chromium running, XSession in both cases. Try to disable possible Add-ons and retry.

Comment: Same here.  Uses ~6% when nothing is playing.  Super sus.

Comment: "It's 2024, and Pulse Audio is still wasting cycles (1-2% on my i9 CPU), and in my country is very dirty energy. This waste needs to stop, and answering this question might be a good start." sure but we switched over to pipewire so ... do the same? And if that does not do it: it is not pulseaudio you need to look at.

Comment: using pipewire with the pulseaudio plugin has no cpu load at all. Running a YT video on my 14 year old Thinkpad T410 leads to about 1%cpu combined (pipewire and the pulseaudio plugin)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest installing "pipewire" - the successor of pulseaudio to your system.

First, you should check if pipewire is already installed on your system:

```
systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager
```

It should be running, but is not used for audio output.

Now you should install the PulseAudio plugins:

```
sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack
```

Next, it is recommended to replace pipewire-media-session with wireplumber:

```
 sudo apt install wireplumber pipewire-media-session-
```

Alsa, which is the layer below pulseaudio should no be reconfigured:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/alsa.conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf /etc/alsa/conf.d/
```

Remove the "old" bluetooth services: (you have installed the new one  above)

```
sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Enable the wireplumber service:

```
systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service
```

Restart your system.
I have followed the instructions from this [page](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/) - but on Ubuntu 22.04. The site also describes on how to revert the changes.

Another instruction (which I haven't tested) can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e)